# How to implement d3.js tooltip by using foreign object in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

# Whenever I add  tag, it is not able to style two children elements to render the tag, which is not enough for two/more tool-tips, while moving my  tag by attributes x and y.#

## Example: I am rendering this  tag, inside my tool-tip component.##

```
  { tooltipData && (
<g>
  <text
  x={tooltipData.xPoint}
  y={tooltipData.yPoint}
  >
    <p> Views: {toolTipData.totalViews}</p>
    <p> Date: {toolTipData.date}</p>
  </text>
</g>
)}
```

### I want to render both

inside the  and should able to style those.###

```
####Can you suggest some method to solve this. thanks in advance.####
```